# List single selection is not working in angular 9.1 after update from angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I'm trying to implement a List with single selection updated my project with angular 9,

```
<mat-selection-list #shoes [multiple]="false">
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes">
    {{shoe}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

it looks like [multiple]="false" is not showing any effect!
I took the example from here:
 https://stackblitz.com/angular/mjqmynpkqnp?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-single-selection-example.html

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.8
Node: 12.18.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 9.1.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                                    Version
--------------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect                  0.901.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular              0.901.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer            0.901.8
@angular-devkit/build-webpack              0.901.8
@angular-devkit/core                       9.1.8
@angular-devkit/schematics                 9.1.8
@angular/cdk                               7.3.7
@angular/cli                               9.1.8
@angular/flex-layout                       9.0.0-beta.31
@angular/http                              7.2.2
@angular/material                          7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                           9.1.8
@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader   7.1.0
@schematics/angular                        9.1.8
@schematics/update                         0.901.8
rxjs                                       6.5.5
typescript                                 3.8.3
webpack                                    4.42.0
```

Comment: seems working fine, can you cross check

Comment: it's hard to help you without further information as the example you are providing is working with angular 9.

Comment: I'm importing only MatSelectModule, MatListModule do I need to Import smth else?

Comment: Can you try with `multiple="false"`?

Comment: Tried with multiple="false" is the same, but when I tried with [multiple]="false" from visual studio code has the error   " If 'mat-selection-list' is an Angular component and it has 'multiple' input, then verify that it is part of this module."

Answer (score 1):

The problem was @angular/material version, after `ng update @angular/material` it works fine.